# Next JS - API Routes - Default error handling like Express.js

Tags: node.js, express, next.js

I'm using the API routes in NextJS and I feel there's lots of code duplication at least for default errors where I'm just setting a status code and a message.

Is there a way to have default error handling for all API Routes like the Express first argument's error?

[Default error handling in Express](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html)